How to Copy Android Mediacodec Output Buffer to Another Buffer to Save Video (H264) to File and Also Stream to RTMP (YouTube) at the Same Time
while (true) {
int encoderStatus = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(mBufferInfo, OUTPUT_TIMEOUT_US);
if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
// no output available yet
if (!drainAll) break; // out of while
        } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
            // not expected for an encoder
            mBuffers.onOutputBuffersChanged();

        } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
            // should happen before receiving buffers, and should only happen once
            if (mController.isStarted()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("MediaFormat changed twice.");
            }
            MediaFormat newFormat = mMediaCodec.getOutputFormat();
            mTrackIndex = mController.notifyStarted(newFormat);
            setState(STATE_STARTED);
        } else if (encoderStatus < 0) {
            // let's ignore it
        } else {
            ByteBuffer encodedData = mBuffers.getOutputBuffer(encoderStatus);

            // Codec config means that config data was pulled out and fed to the muxer
            // when we got the INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED status. Ignore it.
            boolean isCodecConfig = (mBufferInfo.flags
                    & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) != 0;
            if (!isCodecConfig && mController.isStarted() && mBufferInfo.size != 0) {

                // adjust the ByteBuffer values to match BufferInfo (not needed?)
                encodedData.position(mBufferInfo.offset);
                encodedData.limit(mBufferInfo.offset + mBufferInfo.size);

                // Store mStartTimeUs and mLastTimeUs, useful to detect the max length
                // reached and stop recording when needed.
                if (mFirstTimeUs == Long.MIN_VALUE) {
                    mFirstTimeUs = mBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs;
                }
                mLastTimeUs = mBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs;

                // Adjust the presentation times. Subclasses can pass a presentation time in any
                // reference system - possibly some that has no real meaning, and frequently,
                // presentation times from different encoders have a different time-base.
                // To address this, encoders are required to call notifyFirstFrameMillis
                // so we can adjust here - moving to 1970 reference.
                // Extra benefit: we never pass a pts equal to 0, which some encoders refuse.
                mBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = (mStartTimeMillis * 1000)
                        + mLastTimeUs - mFirstTimeUs;

               /*IMP*/
               //Here, we need to save encoded data to a file and RTMP at the same time.
            }
            mMediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);

            // Check for the maxLength constraint (with appropriate conditions)
            // Not needed if drainAll because we already were asked to stop
            if (!drainAll
                    && !mMaxLengthReached
                    && mFirstTimeUs != Long.MIN_VALUE
                    && mLastTimeUs - mFirstTimeUs > mMaxLengthUs) {
                onMaxLengthReached();
                break;
            }

            // Check for the EOS flag so we can call onStopped.
            if ((mBufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                onStopped();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

please search for /IMP/ in above code.
/IMP/ where I need to save buffers for later use and before releaseOutputBuffer() is called. We need to copy the mediacodec output buffer to another output buffer for asynchronous saving to a file (.mp4) and RTMP streaming.

Please, explain what you are trying to do overall and why you want to copy buffers. Also, please edit the question to make it more readable.
